# PMD Eclipse Plugin is not working in Kepler

Tags: eclipse, pmd, eclipse-kepler

I am using pmd-eclipse plugin 4.0.0.201211080927. In Indigo i am able to run the pmd rules successfully. But when i run it in Kepler, it is not showing anything. But in the eclipse log i can see the following Info message,

```
Review code command terminated. 188 rules were executed against 1 files.
```

Is there any configuration should be done in kepler to work with pmd?

Comment: I installed it and it worked just like that. - Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: Yes. Here i am using one customer pmd rule generated as jar file from indigo. Is it causing any problem?